# Way to disable windows from resizing while dragging but allow keyboard shortcut resizing?

Tags: shortcut-keys

I'd like to be able to tap a keyboard shortcut and have a window "snap" to the left side of the screen. However I hate it when I'm trying to move windows around and the window keeps trying to resize from my drag actions. So I'd like to enable a keyboard shortcut to perform this function but disable this function from occurring while dragging windows.

1. Is there a way I can safely disable the drag-to-resize action? (I hear CCSM is dangerous to use so I prefer not to use it. If CCSM is the only way, will Precise have a setting for this in the System Settings?)
2. Is there a keyboard shortcut (or can I create one) that will "snap" the window to the left side of the screen? Like on Windows I can tap Shift+Super+Left to snap a window to the left side of the screen.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your questions is yes (with a catch), but you have to use CCSM.

You can resize Windows using a shortcut key:

[image]

However, I'm not 100% sure that you can stop Windows from resizing when you hit screen borders.

As for having them snap to certain edges, the "Grid" plugin can do just that.

[image]